# PayPal IPN - Profile or Notify_URL

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

Just a quick question, actually related to the last question I posted.

If I specify the notify_url for PayPal's IPN, do I need to have that set in my profile or will PayPal send the same data without it in the profile?

I was reading the document and it says I can set it for adaptive payments, but I'm not using adaptive payments.

Basically:
If I set the notify_url, do I need IPN set in my profile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to set the IPN listener URL in your profile. PayPal sends the IPN message to the listener specified in the notification URL for a specific button or API operation instead of the listener specified in your Profile. If you are only using one IPN listener, then I would set it in your PayPal profile also.